# FileNotFoundException on invoking remote service in Service Fabric [On Premise]

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I have a question about throwing exceptions in SF Service – I have a problem on deserializing exception on other remote service that is placed in the same cluster (but is from other service type from other solution). I have tried throwing custom exceptions and have problem with deserialization and switched to throw simple Exception type with message from original exception but it is still failing on client side looking for library from the source service. I don’t know why remote service is looking for this library when simple exception is throwed. When there is no exception invoking remote service is working fine.

I'm using solution from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting

```
IMyService helloWorldClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IMyService>(new Uri("fabric:/MyApplication/MyHelloWorldService"));
string message = await helloWorldClient.Test("", "", DateTime.Now);

public interface IMyService : IService
{
   Task Test(string arg, string arg2, DateTime date);
}
```

and I'm getting this:

```
Failed to deserialize and get remote exception  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'XXX.ServiceFabricCommon, Version=6.60.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name: 'XXX.ServiceFabricCommon, Version=6.60.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)…
```

Comment: Could you post sample of code where exception is thrown?

Comment: This is same as helloWorlClient - simple two lines of code. Interface is copied to client service (no binary sharing) and this is all. The server is implementing same service with one method and simple types as arguments (I added this to original post). The last thing I forgot is that on local cluster it is working and failing after deploy to our SIT environment.